# Azure logic App - Fails to complete the message in a queue

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues, azure-logic-apps

I have a queue and couple of Azure functions in Azure Logic App.

An Azure function takes 5 minutes and when the event "Complete the message in queue" runs in logic app, it fails.
Following is the output.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Failed to complete the message with the lock token '{the-guid}'. The lock on the message has been lost.",
  "source": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

It was not happening a week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock duration of a message is configurable if you navigate to Service Bus -> Queue -> Properties. Consider extending it longer than  5 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The max Lock duration of ServiceBus queue is 5 minutes, we can't extend it longer than 5 minutes currently. So if the azure function takes 5 minutes that event "Complete the message in queue", it will fail to complete the message.

> Additional :If your function is on a Consumption plan, it is not allow to run a function more than 5 minutes. More info please refer to [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/75)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now you can change it from the Overview:
[image]